# Class Error Unexpected token Global

Tags: apex, scheduled-apex, error

I need some help, I have created the following (see below) 
However I am getting the following error : Error:

> Compile Error: unexpected token: global at line 28 column 0

I do not understand why I am getting this error message ?

```
global class batchELQA_Delete implements Database.Batchable<ELQA_Marketing_Activity__c>
{
    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC)
    {
        String query = 'Select Id FROM ELQA_Marketing_Activity__c WHERE CreatedDate < LAST_N_DAYS:180';
        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }

    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<ELQA_Marketing_Activity__c> scope)
    {
         delete scope;
         DataBase.emptyRecycleBin(scope);  
    }   
    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){}     

}

// to schedule this to run everyday create a scheduled class:
//  This will cause the above class to run.   
global class SchedularForBatchApex implements Schedulable {

   global void execute(SchedulableContext sc) {
      ID BatchId = Database.executeBatch(new batchELQA_Delete(), 2000);
   } 

   Public static void SchedulerMethod() {
      string con_exp= ’0 0 1 * * ?’;
      System.schedule(‘batchELQA_Delete’, con_exp, new SchedularForBatchApex());
}
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can't have two classes in the same file. Instead, you can write it like this:

```
global class batchELQA_Delete implements Database.Batchable<SObject>, Schedulable {
    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
        String query = 'Select Id FROM ELQA_Marketing_Activity__c WHERE CreatedDate < LAST_N_DAYS:180';
        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }

    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<SObject> scope) {
         delete scope;
         DataBase.emptyRecycleBin(scope);  
    }

    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){

    }

   global void execute(SchedulableContext sc) {
      ID BatchId = Database.executeBatch(new batchELQA_Delete(), 2000);
   }

   Public static void SchedulerMethod() {
      string con_exp= '0 0 1 * * ?';
      System.schedule('batchELQA_Delete', con_exp, new batchELQA_Delete());
   }

}
```

Comment: Hi SFDCFOX 
I get the following Error: Compile Error: line 23:22 no viable alternative at character '’' at line 23 column 22

When pasting the whole code into an apex clas. MPHh :(

Comment: Masond3, try changing the quotes around the con_exp from   ’ to '.

Comment: HI Samuel De Rycke, i changed the quotations from ’0 0 1 * * ?’ to '0 0 1 * * ?' and also around 'batchELQA_Delete', but i now get the following error  Compile Error: Invalid type: SchedularForBatchApex at line 24 column 56

Comment: I'll check the code again. I only did a copy paste.

Comment: Those quotes are wrong. Replace them with '.

Comment: Hi SFDCFOX
I have re-pasted the code accross with your changes, however i still getting errors.can you have look and see where its gone wrong ?

Comment: The final call to schedule the code was wrong (again, copy-paste problem). This code compiles in my org (but won't run, because I didn't build a custom object for it).